# Get parameters in actions using zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

How to get parameters from below url

domain.com/admin/edit/12

I want to access this value (12) in edit function.

I searched around but didn't found any inbuilt solution in zend framework.
Even in other framework it works easily.
Like in codeIgnitor it works as segment and function parameter.

Comment: you want answer for codeigniter or zend-framework

Comment: @saurabh2836 can you read properly, I am looking solution like CI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How I can see from code , you have `Admin_Controller` & some action `edit` ( by default routing) . For getting edit value , U need generate urls like  `domain.com/admin/edit/id/12/` (for example) . And than in action `edit` use next:

```
$id = $this->_request->getParam('id',0);
if ($id){
   //get info for edit by ID 
}
```

**EDIT**

IF you still want urls like `domain.com/admin/edit/12`, do next:

```
$uri = $this->_request->getRequestUri(); // or $this->getRequest()->getRequestUri() 
$id = intval(end(explode('/',$uri)));
if($id){
  // do something 
}
```

Comment: This way all works fine but requirement is to show url as domain.com/admin/edit/12. Is this framework  does not provide such feature. In CI it works by default.

Comment: Its looks near by the solution. Is zend framework does not have inbuilt or using route.

Comment: @PraveenD ZF has it all

Comment: which first option? and how it ti right? I am expecting as in CI

Comment: @PraveenD "first option" - where `id` exists in url